# Find a value in json object using lodash methods flatten and find

Tags: lodash

Using lodash i want to find a team whose id is 3229. I tried following but it is not returning anything.

```
    var team = _.chain(data.teams)
        .flatten("divisionTeams")
        .find({"id":3229})
        .value();
```

Here is my plunker code.

http://plnkr.co/edit/UDwzRkX3zkYjyf8UwO7I

**For the Json data please see the file data.js in Plunker.**

Please note i cannot change the json data since i am calling a test api.

Comment: are you also following Pluralsight course on ionic? how come it worked there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`flatten` doesn't take that argument, see [docs](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten). You need to either `map` or `pluck` the `divisionTeams`.

```
_.chain(data.teams)
.pluck('divisionTeams')
.flatten()
.find({id: 3232})
.value();
```

Comment: **Note**: `.pluck` was removed from Lodash v4.0.0 in favor of using `.map`. See https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog#v400. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765963/what-is-the-difference-between-lodashs-map-and-pluck.

Comment: In your example (string as parameter), just use `.map` instead of `.pluck` and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

So if the requirements are to only use flatten, find, and lodash, that's going to be difficult. But using a for loop to get the division teams might be what you're asking.

```
var teams = [];
  for(var e of data.teams) {
    teams.push(e.divisionTeams);
  }
  var blah = _.flatten(teams, true);
  console.log(_.find(blah, function(item) { return item.id == 3222; }));
```