# extract children + parent details using lodash

Tags: lodash, flatten

I have the following JSON structure and I want to extract all the information about a particular team with a given id including the division it belongs to.

```
   {         
"teams":[             
 {  
     "divisionName":"5th Grade - Green",
     "divisionTeams":[  
        {  
           "id":3222,
           "name":"Columbia Ravens 5th",
           "coach":"John Miller"
        },

        {  
           "id":3220,
           "name":"HC Elite OMalley 5th",
           "coach":"Eddie OMalley"
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "divisionName":"5th Grade - White",
     "divisionTeams":[  
        {  
           "id":3225,
           "name":"CBSA Hoyas 5th Grade",
           "coach":"Terrance Taylor"
        },
        {  
           "id":3276,
           "name":"HC Elite 4th Tookes",
           "coach":"Anthony Tookes"
        },
     ]
  }
```

]
}

I tried using the following lodash code, but it came up as undefined.

```
var team=_.chain(data.teams)
                .flatten("divisionTeams")
                .find({"id":3222 })
                .value();
        console.log(team);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a value in json object using lodash methods flatten and find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090260/find-a-value-in-json-object-using-lodash-methods-flatten-and-find)

Answer (score 3):

You can do everything you need with [find()](https://lodash.com/docs#find) and [some()](https://lodash.com/docs#some). There's no need to flatten the arrays.

```
_.find(teams, function(item) {
    return _.some(item.divisionTeams, { id: 3222 });
});
```