# What is the difference between lodash's _.map and _.pluck?

Tags: node.js, lodash

I have the following code, can anyone tell the difference:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const arr = [
    {'fname':'Ali', 'lname': 'Yousuf'},
    {'fname': 'Uzair', 'lname': 'Ali'},
    {'fname': 'Umair', 'lname': 'Khan'}
];

_.map(arr, 'fname');
_.pluck(arr, 'fname');
```

The output is the same, and both functions are not mutating `arr`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the way you're using them, they basically do the same. That's why `.pluck()` was removed from Lodash v4.0.0 in favor of using `.map()` with a string as second argument.

Here's the relevant excerpt from the [changelog](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog):

> Removed `_.pluck` in favor of `_.map` with iteratee shorthand
>
> ```
> var objects = [{ 'a': 1 }, { 'a': 2 }];
>
> // in 3.10.1
> _.pluck(objects, 'a'); // → [1, 2]
> _.map(objects, 'a'); // → [1, 2]
>
> // in 4.0.0
> _.map(objects, 'a'); // → [1, 2]
> ```

Comment: yes, `map` can receive a `function` or a `string` as a parameter, if it receives a `string` it's behavior is going to be like `pluck`. Otherwise its behavior is like `Array.prototype.map`.