# Which is the equivalent of underscore js _.unique and _.pluck in lodash?

Tags: underscore.js, lodash

my code is:

```
var product_list = _.unique(_.pluck(data, 'Product'))
var facility_list = _.unique(_.pluck(data, 'Facility'))
```

I have used underscore js above. Now I need the same functionality to be done with Lodash js. Which one should I Use? Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between lodash's \_.map and \_.pluck?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765963/what-is-the-difference-between-lodashs-map-and-pluck)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `_.map` instead of `_.pluck` and `_.uniq` instead of `_.unique`.

```
var product_list = _.uniq(_.map(data, 'Product'))
var facility_list = _.uniq(_.map(data, 'Facility'))
```